# Update the price on the product page with custom selects

Tags: expresso-store

I'm trying to update the price on the product page, I'm using the "dynamic" price class.

```
<span class="store_product_price">{price}</span>
```

But because I want the options to look nice, I am actually hiding the standard expresso modifiers `<select>` element, then using some custom JS I am updating it, but when I do that, I appear to be missing a function that expresso store uses to update the price in the `store_product_price` class.

Is there a way to call that and update it?

Or will I have to loop on all the "selected" options and update the price manually? Would rather not get into maths for doing this & take advantage of expresso's method. :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to add `.trigger("change")` to the end of my custom JS and it detected the select changing.